# Jquery Dialog box : Displaying 2 dialog box on same page with different jquery-ui-rev.css

Tags: jquery, css

I have 2 Jquery Dialog box on the same page. The look and feel of both the dialog box are different from one another. Since both are referring to same `jquery-ui-rev.css` whatever CSS I apply for one dialog box, its getting applied to other also which I dont want. How can I fix my problem? And tell the dialog box to use a different CSS file for each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Dialog#dialogClass](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#option-dialogClass) to specify individual css classes for different dialogues.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create seperate css file for the each dialog. during the dialog open include the css file and remove the css file when you close the dialog. [Remove or add css file dynamically](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss2.shtml)

This is may be useful for you

Comment: Even the answer from Muthu was very helpful.